# Find the quotient

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

How can I divide $x^3+1+3x2^\frac{1}{3}$ by $x-1+2^\frac{1}{3}$. I tried to rationalise the denominator but that did not work.

Comment: Is the numerator $x^3+1+3\sqrt[3]{2}x$?

Comment: Yes this is the numerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor is linear... would synthetic division not work here?

[image]

This gives

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^3 + 1 + 3\sqrt[3]{2}x}{x-1+\sqrt[3]{2}}&=x^2+(1-\sqrt[3]{2})x+(1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}) \\
&= x^2+x-x\sqrt[3]{2}+1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're working over $\mathbb{R}$ because of the coefficients $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

As $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, then $$x^3 + 3 \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{3}} x +1 = p(x) (x + 2^{\frac{1}{3}} - 1) + r(x)$$ for some $p(x), r(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $ \text{deg}(r(x)) < \text{deg}(x^3 + 3 \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{3}} x + 1) = 3 $ or $ r(x) = 0$.

That is to say, a solution to the long division exists, although it may come with a remainder ($r(x)$).

Comment: $\displaystyle x²+1+\sqrt[3]{4} +x-x\sqrt[3]{2} +\sqrt[3]{2}$ is the solution but I am not able to make it how